# Create a shared object file (.so) from a C project

Tags: c, windows, unity-game-engine, shared-libraries, spatialite

I have downloaded a C project for Spatialite (extension of SQLITE database).
http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/libspatialite-sources/libspatialite-amalgamation-3.0.1.zip

How would I go about creating a .so (shared object library) for Unity3D from that C project?

The target platform is Windows (not Linux/Unix).

Comment: Which system should this `shared object library` be targeted for? The `.so` file extension is usually used by *nix boxes. Windows machines use a `.dll` file extension for their shared libraries.

Comment: I would like to import in unity3d. In unity I write in C#.I need a .so file for my project and not a dll file, cause I run a specific sample test file that loads a .so file.